# Как подключить функцию на frontend с backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

В controllers я создаю функцию логина

```
export const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Пользователь не найден',
      });
    }

    const isValidPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user._doc.passwordHash);

    if (!isValidPass) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Неверный логин или пароль',
      });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: user._id,
      },
      'secret123',
      {
        expiresIn: '30d',
      },
    );

    const { passwordHash, ...userData } = user._doc;
    req.session.fullName = user.fullName;
    
    res.json({
      ...userData,
      token,
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Не удалось авторизоваться',
    });
  }
};
```

Функцию выхода

```
export const logout = async (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json({message: 'Cookies delete'});
  });
}
```

route

```
router.post('/logout', logout)
```

На бэкенд все работает, как мне вызвать эту функцию, через axios, при нажатии кнопки

Вызываю функцию при клике, но ничего не происходит

```
const onClickDeleteCookies = () => {
    try {
      axios.post('/api/auth/logout');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
<Button onClick={onClickDeleteCookies} variant="contained" className={styles.exit2}>
              Delete cookies
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о функции logout, то ты уже создал урл, по которому можно обратиться к серверу.
Теперь на стороне клиента тебе надо сделать POST запрос (не важно, fetch, axios или что-то ещё) по урлу:

```
<хост, где расположен сервер>:<порт сервера >/logout
```

То есть, если ты запускаешь сервер на локальной машине на порту 3000, то тебе надо сделать запрос на урл с методом POST:

```
127.0.0.1:3000/logout
```

Comment: я это сделал, но эффекта 0, будто бы оно не видит его

Comment: Тут много вариантов. Например,
 
1. Запущен ли сервер;
2. Проходит ли запрос в Network;
3. Есть ли логи на стороне сервера;
4. Какие заголовки прилетают к юзеру.

Ну и, если ты хочешь очистить куки, то это можно сделать прямо на клиенте, а сервер просто уведомить об этом.